# how to find directories , compress and save in other location

Tags: playonlinux, find, tar

I have a task -
To search 6 months old directories/files.
1) Tar and save to another location.

Below command works perfectly, but saving to same location where old files exist

```
find . -mtime +180 -exec tar --remove-files -jcvf {}.tar.bz2 {} \;
```

I tried below command to save in another location, but didn't help, can anyone help me out here.

```
find . -mtime +180 -exec tar --remove-files -jcf ../old_file/{}.tar.bz2 {} \;
```

2) To preserve same date/timing , i am trying `--atime-preserve` with `tar`, but could see still new tar file created with today's date

Comment: Please advise the distro you installed (i.e., Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, et al.) and its version. Please click [edit] and add that information to your question; please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: directory ../old_file/{} need to exist.